# Different frames make rigid bodies act differently

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

So I am writing a small script to set initial speeds for objects in the Rigid Body system. It is really bare bones right now, but it essentially sets a keyframe for the selected object on the frame number of a variable called `start_frame`.

The goal of the script is so I can choose a start frame and a speed, and the object will have all of the correct keyframes set so it can just launch off with an initial speed. The problem is that depending on what frame I set `start_frame` to be, the cube reacts differently.

Here is what I mean:

If `start_frame` equals 1, the object is launched and then falls off the plane.
[image]

If `start_frame` equals any number greater than 1, the object doesn't travel as far.
[image]

From what I understand, there shouldn't be any difference because the distance between the start and end keyframes is always the same.

I looked at the graph editor but the only change I am seeing between the two conditions is being shifted, just like it should be.

[image: Animated GIF]

I am so confused why changing the frame from 1 to anything above 1 would give such a different result.

So is there anything special about frame 1?
And if so, how can I avoid this problem in my script?

[image]

Comment: that's because  `end_frame = start_frame + speed` so "end frame" is always "speed" frames away from the "star_frame"

Comment: @Chebhou That is exactly what is supposed to happen. The `start_frame` defines the frame to start the animation on. I just want the cube that is launched to have the same physics no matter what frame it is launched on. I will upload a GIF to explain what I mean.

Comment: if you travel the same distance in the same duration you will end up in the same place no matter what late you are, duration needs to change but in your script it's constant as the distance is , why do you expect the result to be different ?

Comment: @Chebhou The result is different, and that is what is bugging me. I will reword my question and hopefully it will make more sense. For now, take a look at the GIFs I uploaded. The first one `start_frame` set to 1, and the second shows it set to frame 2. The result is different and I am very confused.

Comment: here is what is even weird : if the `start_frame` is odd it will fall off the plane , but if it is even it will stop before, even at larger numbers

Comment: ok I think i found something go to world tab ->rigid_body_world->steps_per_second and set it to 24 (or multiple of 24) and all animations will have the same result

Comment: @Chebhou Thanks a ton! I will look into this a bit more and see if I can make an answer that explains why this is. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in order to fix this problem, the steps per second need to be a multiple of the current frames per second. Not exactly sure why this is, but it will make everything more stable!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the animation starts at `frame_start` and ends at `frame_end` and since `end_frame = start_frame + speed` the duration is always the same but shifted.
To achieve the desired effect the animation duration should get longer when `frame_start` gets larger, one way to do it is to set the first keyframe at 0.
so the first key frame shouldn't be the start_frame :

```
    # First keyframe
    scene.frame_current = 0
    bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert(type='Location')
    print(start_location)
```

---

if you want to start at `frame_start` and end at `frame_end` and get different results you have to change the `frame_end` expression :

```
frame_end = speed + 2*frame_start
```

this way the delay the start the longer the duration is , giving the cube lower speed ( less momentum )  and it will travel shorter