# Simple rigid body physics (Sphere - Box) depends on substep

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I am trying to use Bullet to get physically accurate simulations by setting up the simulations through Blender (2.73a or 2.75a). 
It seems to be very unreliable with respect to the **physics_step_sub** property.

Most annoyingly, a collision is often **missed**, and the object gets stuck. I hope someone spots an obvious mistake.

I set up a minimal working example:

- a sphere (rigid body, collision_bound_type: SPHERE) that's given an initial velocity, and
- a wall (actor, static, BOX), that it bounces back from.
- no gravity
- elasticity 1 for both objects.

The outcome changes based on the substeps parameter. 
Which would be ok, but which is closest to actual physics?
I read, that it's not good to have small objects, so I enlarged the scene, the outcome is similar: [tests.zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6RALYQZbAvQN1ZaNTB5Q05yeHc/view?usp=sharing)

The minimal blend file can be found here: [scene.blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6RALYQZbAvQMUU3VDk2dW9XZ0U/view?usp=sharing)

I tried adjusting the magic "*game.radius*" parameter, but it only changes anything, if it's too large and the objects immediately start to distance themselves.

Collision margins don't seem influence this behaviour.

Thanks!

Comment: see the comments on this http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28876/different-frames-make-rigid-bodies-act-differently/

Comment: Sounds like you are using the game engine. Have you tried using the rigid body sim [outside of the BGE](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/34400/599)?